# How to check MySQL table updates and send mail using cron job

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, cron, cron-task

I write a request program which it contains send mail automatically whenever a new data is inserted. I want to use cron to active the request.

Whenever MySQL is updated I want to receive a mail automatically.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following solutions:

1) Add column 'Status' with default value = 'INSERTED' and create a simple program which will retrieve rows with status 'Inserted' minutely and send email notification. After the sending an email, you should update status to 'SENDED' or something like this.

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table` 
ADD COLUMN `STATUS` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT 'INSERTED';
```

Your application are scheduled by cron job should retrieve data by the query:

```
select <some_fields>
from  <your_table>
where status = 'INSERTED'; 

<send email logic>

update <your_table>
set status = 'SENDED'; 
where status = 'INSERTED';
```

2) Create trigger which will insert information about new rows into separate table. The next steps the same as in previous approach.

```
CREATE TRIGGER save_inserted_data AFTER INSERT ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      insert into log_table (id)
      values (:new.id)
END;

<send email logic>

delete from log_table;
```

And you should add some logic which will take in account new rows during sending email. I.e,

- 3 rows was inserted
- you retrieve 3 rows for email notification
- someone add new one
- need to mark/delete only 3 rows (without new one)

Comment: could u plze explain me with the example